# How to obfuscate outgoing traffic if we don't want to use VPN?

Tags: internet

If we say that I cannot trust my internet-service-provider regarding privacy, how can I obfuscate the outgoing traffic on my line?

So the ISP will not see that what am I actually doing.

Randomly generate false traffic? Use ToR?

Comment: Do you want to prevent them from seeing: **a)** the *content* of the traffic, **b)** the *exact URL* (/foo/bar.html), or **c)** which *domains* (security.stackexchange.com) you visit?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use secure connections (SSL) they will "not" be able to see the data you are transmitting.

However if your concern is about they knowing where are you connecting to, then your best bet would be to use Tor, as you are discarding the use of a VPN service. Notice that even using Tor, your connection goes through your ISP (the first hop), however, they are not able to see what's your real destination, only the first Tor node you're going to use.

Comment: SSL can be decrypted fairly quickly. https://www.gigamon.com/products/technology/ssl-decryption

Comment: @l1thal that link you provided is just marketing "bullshit", but yes, SSL can be decrypted, that's why I wrote *"not"*.

Comment: Ah alright, I thought you were trying to emphasize the word and not suggest anything like that. Just trying to add things I think will help =P